# What is the group of proper rotations of a rectangular box of length 3 cm, depth 2 cm, and height 2 cm?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is the group of proper rotations of a rectangular box of length 3 cm, depth 2 cm, and height 2 cm?

I've found 8 proper rotations by symmetry but I don't think that is all of the proper rotations. Any help would be great, Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you put a $2 \times 2$ face on the table, you can rotate it by any number of quarter turns around a vertical axis, by half turns around two horizontal axes through the face centers, and by half turns around two horizontal axes through the centers of opposite vertical sides.  That gives an eight element group.